# Properly formatted correlogram in Python

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I am struggling in accomplishing a task which I thought was extremely simple.

Starting from a correlation matrix,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=+1, size=(5,5)))
```

I would like to generate a visualization/table as similar as possible to the following: 
[image: This layout is generated by an R package for correlation plots]

So far I have been able only to obtain the following result:

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap="RdBu_r", low = 0, high = 0)
```

[image]

Besides being very ugly, the main issues I found in my Python solution is that color palette does not properly work in the range [-1; +1], like in the ideal example.

Could you please help me in finding a solution which generate a result as similar as possible to my ideal layout?

**It is important the solution to output a Pandas table** because I will enrich with a `set_table_styles` function

Comment: So the colour comes from the scale of the values, but what about the size of the dots? Is it to do with the absolute value?

Comment: The size of the dot represents the magnitude in absolute value of the correlation index. For example, correlation of +1 (or -1) is associated to a dot of biggest size, whereas correlation of 0 is associated to dot of smallest size.
Note that the color should range from -1 to +1 with white color for 0.

Comment: Okay I see... Giving it a try :)